# 3d-surface plot with overlay points in javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, plot

I want to visualize a stochastic optimization algorithm written in javascript and so I'm looking to plot 3d surfaces in javascript with overlay scatter points. But I can't find any library that support this. Is there any? [javascript-surface-plot](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-surface-plot/) is almost what I want but it doesn't *seem* to support adding points onto the chart. I want something like the chart in [this](http://www.originlab.com/www/products/images/3d_curve_fitting.600.png) picture.

Comment: Where can I find it? Can't find it with google..

Comment: I don't suppose you meant [three.js](http://threejs.org/)? It seems promising but would require doing some wrapping work to enable charting. I will probably go with this if I can't find any "high level" interface. three.js even works with my non-WebGl supportive browser for some reason. Nice.

Comment: Sorry, I meant D3.js.

Comment: d3.js has no support for 3d surface plots as far as I can see.

Comment: Hmm. three.js does only seem to work with my non-webgl-browser for the three.js editor. Software rendered I suppose.